# filtering data not equal to a specific text jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

Hi ihave loaded  a jqgrid with jason data.

I have this filtering

```
  //  Fetch the text from our <input> control
            var searchString = 'N';
​
            //  Prepare to pass a new search filter to our jqGrid
            var f = { groupOp: "AND", rules: [] };
​
            //  Remember to change the following line to reflect the jqGrid column you want to search for your string in
            //  In this code, I'm searching through the CAR_NO column.
​
            f.rules.push({ field: "CLOSEDDATE", op: "cn", data: searchString });
​
            var grid = $('#Auditgrid');
​
            grid[0].p.search = f.rules.length > 0;
            $.extend(grid[0].p.postData, { filters: JSON.stringify(f) });
            grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1 }]);
```

It seach close date with `N` value on it
but what i want is to filter data with a `CLOSEDDATE` not equal to `N`

is it possible with my current filtering code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this - you will need just to look at the available options for searching in [language file or documentation](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/searching/#configuration).

Opposite to operator contain is **not contaion** coded as **nc**

In your case this can look like

```
...
f.rules.push({ field: "CLOSEDDATE", op: "nc", data: searchString });
```